# Get the string between 2 specifics characters

Tags: vb.net

I want to do an application.

In this appplication I want to get the string between 2 characters I've chosen.

For exemple : "Hello world".

If I chose the characters "e" and "d", this will get "llo worl"

I'm trying to help of the Substring method in the Microsoft documentation. But I don't find how I can put the last limit of the string.

Thank you for your help

Comment: Use `.LastIndexOf('d')` method on your string.

Comment: i'm about to write the code for this.. hold on

Comment: Thanks a lot, but can you show me an example ? @vendettamit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Dim MainString As String 'the main string 
Dim FirstChar As String 'first character
Dim lastchar As String 'second char
Dim finalastring As String 'final string after the work is done

Dim FirstCharIndex As Integer 'the index where first char is located
Dim LastCharIndex As Integer 'the index where last char is located

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    MainString = TextBox1.Text 'Hello World
    FirstChar = TextBox2.Text 'e
    lastchar = TextBox3.Text 'd

    FirstCharIndex = MainString.IndexOf(FirstChar) 'this will return 1 in this condition
    LastCharIndex = MainString.LastIndexOf(lastchar) 'this will return 10

    'now, Final String

    finalastring = MainString.Substring(FirstCharIndex, (LastCharIndex - FirstCharIndex))

    TextBox4.Text = finalastring



End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It helps me a lot but, there're some bugs in the program. For example when I have a lot of the same character (lastchar) it takes the last of these instead of stop to the first he meets.

Comment: use `.IndexOf(LastChar)`

Answer (score 1):

You can still use `Substring` in order to accomplish that:

```
    Public Sub Main()
        Dim test as String = "Hello World"
        Console.WriteLine(StringBetweenChars(test,"e","d"))

    End Sub

    Public Function StringBetweenChars(ByVal fullText, ByVal start, ByVal ending) as String
        Dim x,j as integer
        x = fullText.IndexOf(start) + 1
        j = fullText.IndexOf(ending) 
        If(j <> -1) Then
            return fullText.Substring(x, j-x)           
            Else
            return fullText.Substring(x, fullText.Length - x)
        End If
    End function
```

> **This prints out: `llo Worl`**

Comment: Thanks a lot your function helped me a lot too !